# Why are REGOs are so bad?

Tags: climate-change, energy

Firstly, a REGO is a [Renewable Energy Guarantee of Origin](https://www.ofgem.gov.uk/environmental-and-social-schemes/renewable-energy-guarantees-origin-rego/renewable-energy-guarantees-origin-rego-electricity-suppliers-and-generators). We have these in the UK, and they are probably quite self-explanatory: a windfarm (for example) generates a certain amount of kWh which are then pumped into the UK Grid. This then gives them a certificate stating that x kWh of sustainable energy have been contributed. They can sell these certificates to anyone interested in buying them. In your country you may have a different mechanism, or just a different name: I have no idea.

Secondly, I'm slightly shocked that this appears to be best fit in terms of Stack Exchange forums: I'd have expected one dedicated to Climate Change, or maybe the environment ...

---

In the UK there is a lot of talk about "greenwashing" when it comes to the supply of electricity, and in fact there has been for quite a long time. The supplier I'm with, which has generally one of the better reps, claims that it is supplying "100% green" electricity to my house. But in fact it buys lots of electricity generated from hydrocarbons. It is allowed to claim "100% green" because it also buys these REGOs.

Unless I have misunderstood, REGOs are a way of, if not "overcoming" this problem, at least trying to neutralise it. I have read [this Ecotricity page](https://www.ecotricity.co.uk/our-green-energy/greenwashing) on the subject, and I still don't understand. In particular I don't understand why REGOs are (said to be) so cheap.

Is the key to understanding this issue that there are vast numbers of consumers (perhaps not just domestic consumers) who couldn't care less what kind of source their energy is coming from? Otherwise, wouldn't each precious kWh from sustainable sources be carefully bought by the various consumers (of all kinds) up and down the UK? How come vast amounts of REGOs are being produced (e.g. by a given windfarm somewhere) and are nevertheless cheap as chips, in 2023?

NB I've also got the impression that there's an international dimension to this which may make things even more impenetrable.

If my description of this situation is anything like close to the truth, this would imply that the reasoning behind "Level 3" on the Ecotricity page is puzzingly disingenuous. In the sense that it's a diversion to imagine that suppliers MUST generate their own electricity. In reality, if all consumers across the board were demanding electricity from sustainable sources, the price of REGOs would rise and create demand for construction of new renewable capacity. So the real question would then be: who are these consumers who are unconcerned about sustainable electricity?

If you speak from a position of knowledge about these matters I'd be happy to hear any explanations.